# CSS - How to display pair of DIV's inline, that are inside a full-width div?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I have some HTML, generated by Drupal and Views Slideshow, that (generally) looks like:

```
<div id="banner">
  <div id="image1" class="hidden"> Image .. </div>
  <div id="text1" class="hidden"> Text .. </div>
  <div id="image2" class="active"> Image .. </div>
  <div id="text2" class="active"> Text .. </div>
</div>
<div id="counter">
  <div class="item1 hidden">1</div>
  <div class="item2 active">2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The content of #banner (the image and text) rotates periodically, and the content of #counter displays a bullet image identifying the active image, which is selected by adding and removing CSS to each #counter child in turn.  The output is a bit similar to http://www.slidesjs.com/, except with the added line of text.

I am omitting the actual CSS and HTML because it's rather verbose.

I am trying to display the contents of #counter inline (which I can do with #counter .item { float: left }), then position it next to #text.

I'm not able to position #content next to #text, and if possible, only through CSS.

Hopefully that's clear-ish.  I'm having a hard time putting this into words.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you currently have, and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? If not, could you provide an example image of what you're looking for.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#banner {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#counter {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="image1" class="hidden"> Image .. </div>
    <div id="text1" class="hidden"> Text .. </div>
    <div id="image2" class="active"> Image .. </div>
    <div id="text2" class="active"> Text .. </div>
  </div>
  <div id="counter">
    <div class="item1 hidden">1</div>
    <div class="item2 active">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```